# Build the LLVM-IR Code with AddressSanitizer Pass using opt command

Tags: rust, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I have some question about the building process with AddressSanitizer using opt. I want to build the LLVM-IR Code(.ll) using opt command with specific LLVM Pass like AddressSanitizer(asan). To do this, I use the commend line like below:

```
`opt -asan Input.ll -o Output.ll`
```

But there are some error that it is necessary to process the pre LLVM-Pass like ASanGlobalsMetadataAnalysis and the error message like below:

```
LLVM ERROR: The ASanGlobalsMetadataAnalysis is required to run before AddressSanitizer can run
PLEASE submit a bug report to https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/ and include the crash backtrace.
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: opt -asan ASan_Input.ll -o your_output.ll
 #0 0x0000563ad350c455 PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) Signals.cpp:0:0
 #1 0x0000563ad3509b4e SignalHandler(int) Signals.cpp:0:0
 #2 0x00007f0a0ea42520 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x42520)
 #3 0x00007f0a0ea96a7c __pthread_kill_implementation ./nptl/./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44:76
 #4 0x00007f0a0ea96a7c __pthread_kill_internal ./nptl/./nptl/pthread_kill.c:78:10
 #5 0x00007f0a0ea96a7c pthread_kill ./nptl/./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89:10
 #6 0x00007f0a0ea42476 gsignal ./signal/../sysdeps/posix/raise.c:27:6
 #7 0x00007f0a0ea287f3 abort ./stdlib/./stdlib/abort.c:81:7
 #8 0x0000563ad3448467 llvm::report_fatal_error(llvm::Twine const&, bool) (/home/wldns190/rust/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/llvm/bin/opt+0x27c2467)
 #9 0x0000563ad34485ce (/home/wldns190/rust/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/llvm/bin/opt+0x27c25ce)
#10 0x0000563ad2f9a511 llvm::AddressSanitizerPass::run(llvm::Function&, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function>&) (/home/wldns190/rust/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/llvm/bin/opt+0x2314511)
#11 0x0000563ad11ba526 llvm::detail::PassModel<llvm::Function, llvm::AddressSanitizerPass, llvm::PreservedAnalyses, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function> >::run(llvm::Function&, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function>&) (/home/wldns190/rust/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/llvm/bin/opt+0x534526)
#12 0x0000563ad16b8628 llvm::detail::PassModel<llvm::Function, llvm::PassManager<llvm::Function, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function> >, llvm::PreservedAnalyses, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function> >::run(llvm::Function&, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function>&) (/home/wldns190/rust/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/llvm/bin/opt+0xa32628)
#13 0x0000563ad2bd4c94 llvm::ModuleToFunctionPassAdaptor::run(llvm::Module&, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Module>&) (/home/wldns190/rust/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/llvm/bin/opt+0x1f4ec94)
#14 0x0000563ad11ba7c6 llvm::detail::PassModel<llvm::Module, llvm::ModuleToFunctionPassAdaptor, llvm::PreservedAnalyses, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Module> >::run(llvm::Module&, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Module>&) (/home/wldns190/rust/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/llvm/bin/opt+0x5347c6)
#15 0x0000563ad2bce9a5 llvm::PassManager<llvm::Module, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Module> >::run(llvm::Module&, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Module>&) (/home/wldns190/rust/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/llvm/bin/opt+0x1f489a5)
#16 0x0000563ad11c5d1d llvm::runPassPipeline(llvm::StringRef, llvm::Module&, llvm::TargetMachine*, llvm::TargetLibraryInfoImpl*, llvm::ToolOutputFile*, llvm::ToolOutputFile*, llvm::ToolOutputFile*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::StringRef>, llvm::opt_tool::OutputKind, llvm::opt_tool::VerifierKind, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool) (/home/wldns190/rust/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/llvm/bin/opt+0x53fd1d)
#17 0x0000563ad10ef4fd main (/home/wldns190/rust/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/llvm/bin/opt+0x4694fd)
#18 0x00007f0a0ea29d90 __libc_start_call_main ./csu/../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58:16
#19 0x00007f0a0ea29e40 call_init ./csu/../csu/libc-start.c:128:20
#20 0x00007f0a0ea29e40 __libc_start_main ./csu/../csu/libc-start.c:379:5
#21 0x0000563ad11b8a95 _start (/home/wldns190/rust/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/llvm/bin/opt+0x532a95)
Aborted
```

So, I wonder that how to build the LLVM-IR Code with AddressSanitizer Pass using opt commend Line?
Is there any shell script or commend Line to build the LLVM-IR Code with ASan??

Have a nice Day!

Comment: Why is your question tagged `Rust`? What part of your question is `Rust` specific?

Comment: Be aware that if you want to run LLVM sanitizers in Rust you don't have to go to that length; all you need to do is `export RUSTFLAGS="-Z sanitizer=address"`, and then build normally using a `nightly` toolchain. (be aware that there used to be a bug where you have to specify `--target` then, even if you are building natively; and you might have to install the `llvm` package to be able to resolve the backtraces)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I tagged it with "rust" because I'm testing a Rust program. I want to compile Rust code into LLVM-IR and then recompile LLVM-IR into a binary using the AddressSanitizer pass. However, I'm encountering issues during the transition from LLVM-IR to a binary. During the build process, it seems that the Rust standard library is linked into the object file.

Is there a way to explicitly disable the linking of the Rust standard library during the LLVM-IR to binary compilation process?